# System using over 80% of memory

Tags: windows-10

I've just started getting this in the past day, so I don't know what could be causing it.

I'm on Windows 10, and before tonight I've never had this issue.

[image: Screenshot of used memory]

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  A lot of people have a big misconception that having a lot of memory in use is bad thing.   They think they need to free up as much memory as possible.  This is *not* a bad thing.  This is a *very* good thing.  Someone on SU posted an excellent answer to this very question before.  I looked for it, but cant find it.  I hope someone else can.

Comment: @Keltari I looked this up elsewhere as well and I found that it wasn't a good thing

Comment: You can either reboot your PC, or just keep leave your PC idle for a long while. "system" is Microsoft's service, thus, don't worry too much. In my case, I am using an 8 eight years old laptop built for Windows XP with a 1.3GHz single-core CPU. Since Windows 10 is a newer, heavier OS, I see that kind of thing a lots when Microsoft's services working and taking a huge chunk of memory + CPU. It should die down after a while.

Comment: Welcome to the new paradigm, where empty RAM is wasted RAM. There's little point in having all that fast stuff sitting idle, when it could be ready to execute the next action. If anything is needed that isn't already in RAM, then it takes no time at all to dump the unneeded to make room for the required.

Comment: Unfortunately one misconception about free RAM has spawned another misconception. The memory use % in task manager does not include cached RAM, so it should normally be well below 50% at startup regardless of any Superfetch activity.

Comment: @Keltari Are you thinking of this? [Windows says RAM ran out while there is still 4 GB of physical memory available](https://superuser.com/a/943185)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows says RAM ran out while there is still 4 GB of physical memory available](http://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available)

Comment: @TBBT I'd agree, I used a 64-bit windows 7 OS on a designed Windows XP Home 32-bit laptop and had an issue kinda like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long while of looking around and fixing things on my own, I finally found the issue to my problem.

I got curious whenever @James mentioned Superfetch, and I looked up on it, just to find out that it was my problem. My problem, after disabling it, magically went away and hasn't popped back up in the tiniest bit.

Comment: This was never a problem, superfetch was doing precisely what it was designed to do.

Comment: @Fopedush Then why do I get performance improvements when it's disabled?