# How do I find what's eating up 1.5GB of my memory?

Tags: windows, memory, process, task-manager

I have a problem that something eats my memory and now my PC is slow , the task manager doesn't show the process who use  that part of my memory i take captures of RAMMAP , resource monitor and process explorer but i didn't understand how to find out which process eats the memory. 
so what i have to do ? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows says RAM ran out while there is still 4 GB of physical memory available](http://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available)

Comment: don't use Chrome ;) It is a RAM-"eater"

Comment: chrome eats just 370MB where is 1.7 GB ?

Comment: no, Chrome uses multiple processes. that sums up to a larger number.