# Out of physical memory on notebook - Correct approach?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-systems, memory-limit

I have a Fedora 21 on my notebook and it sometimes runs out of memory. The notebook has 4GB of system RAM and the OS takes up only about 450MB of disk space.

I am sure that the culprit is Chromium; which seems to have memory leaks. The problem is that the OS freezes and only hard restart works. I found some info about “Out Of Memory” killer, but it was mostly server stuff.

What is the best approach to this problem on workstations?

Comment: Are you running out of virtual memory or physical memory there is a huge difference.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, physical.

Comment: How much physical memory do you have?

Comment: @DrZoo 4GB and OS takes only about 450MB

Comment: Are you running Fedora without any swap file?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, i have SSD and it is one of recommended optimizations.

Comment: That recommended optimization was only true for first genration SSD's. Modern SSD's don't have the lifetime issue and it is perfectly file (infact you will get better performance) to put swap on a SSD. Please read [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available/943185#943185) its about windows, but the logic behind why you need a swap file is the same. You are running out of virtual memory because you have no swap.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain And the "overprovisioning" of file system is obsolete too?

Comment: No, overprovisioning is how they solved it, that combined with better flash memory that has more write cycles. First generation drives had very little overprovisioned space to swap out bad cells.

Comment: Can you add the output of `free` and `df -h` to your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your problems is you are running out of virtual memory, this is causing your system to lock up long before you actually run out of available physical memory. You need to enable a swap partition on your system and you should see your lockup problems disappear.

Please read [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available/943185#943185) from a question that was having similar problems to you but on Windows, it explains in detail why you need a swap file on a modern operating system.

Not running swap on a SSD was only true for first generation drives from the early 2000's. Modern SSD's lifespan have no issue with running swap on it, in fact if you have the choose between a spinning hard disk drive and a SSD putting the swap on SSD will improve your performance.