# 34 GB of commited memory but no app actually commited that much

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, virtual-memory, event-viewer

Sometimes I encounter Out of memory errors and Windows Event Viewer shows this (translated):

> Resource-Exhaustion-Detector: A lack of virtual memory in the system was successfully detected. The largest amount of virtual memory was allocated to the following
>   programs: **10582**573056 bytes were allocated for myapp.exe (12412),
>   **916**819968 bytes were allocated for firefox.exe (18240) and **794**206208
>   bytes were allocated for firefox.exe (13724).

myapp.exe allocated 10 GB, Firefox.exe-s allocated totally ~4.5 GB, some other stuff 10x150MB (as I check later in Task Manager), so total commit should be 16 GB but since I receive these lack of memory warning I assume that the real commit is about 34 GB (32 GB of RAM + 2 GB pagefile).

What could be that hidden thing with big commit that is neither shown in Task Manager processes nor reported by Resource-Exhaustion-Detector?

Is cached memory shown in Task Manager counted towards commited? If counted then why isn't it freed when another app tries to allocate for its needs (as I understand cached memory just fills not used RAM and should be immediately freed when that memory is required)?

Here is a screenshot of different time when Task Manager shows 19.3 GB commited but if I sum everything in allocated column in Details tab it's ~14.3 GB, not 19.3. 
[image]

**Update**

**This is not a duplicate** of [Resource-Exhaustion-Detector: out of virtual memory, but plenty of RAM available](https://superuser.com/questions/1516596/34-gb-of-commited-memory-but-no-app-actually-commited-thatt-much)

In that previous question I asked why I receive out of memory when I have free RAM, now I know the answer - because I'm out of commited memory. Now I'm asking why I'm running of commited memory while no app actually commits that much. They are different.

None of these either answer my question because they are about having physical memory free but receiving Out of memory errors, but I'm asking about reasons why I have no free virtual memory:

- [Windows says RAM ran out while there is still 4 GB of physical memory available](https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available)
- [Commit charge is 100% full but physical memory is just 60% when using no page file](https://superuser.com/questions/482678/commit-charge-is-100-full-but-physical-memory-is-just-60-when-using-no-page-fi)
- [Why is my "Committed" memory so much higher than my actual RAM space?](https://superuser.com/questions/971967/why-is-my-committed-memory-so-much-higher-than-my-actual-ram-space)

Comment: @Vlad Much better. I've reopened this one for you.

Comment: When looking at the processes and their memory consumption I would recommend to use Sysinternals Process Explorer instead of the TaskManager and enable all the different memory columns. This tool also has the advantage that it does not suffer from any translation (usually more on obfuscation that a translation).

Comment: Your pagefile is extremely small. It is normally recommended for it to be the size of the RAM. How are you getting the numbers for the programs?

Comment: @harrymc I summed Task Manager's allocated column. Now rechecked with sum of PagedMemorySize in PowerShell and it's 17 GB commited by processes (of 22 GB total commited).

Comment: @Vlad - Have you set the size of allow Windows to set the size?

Comment: @Ramhound I set the page file size to 2 GB

Comment: @Vlad - You are getting virtual memory errors due to that fact.  Task Manager is nearly useless compared to RAMMAP

Comment: @Ramhound ok, I understand that I don't get these errors if I had bigger pagefile. But anyway why so much memory is allocated? What is it allocated for?

Comment: RAMMAP holds the answers you seek

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded it but it doesn't show anything useful for this issue

Comment: @Vlad - How about providing a screenshot and allowing the community to decide that?  I know exactly what I am looking for within RAMMAP.

Comment: @Ramhound screenshot of what exactly? which tab, sorted by which columns?