# What to add to get the committed memory size on windows?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, task-manager

According to task manager my committed memory is 7.1 GB but I can only see my processes using around 3.6GB

I'm using Powershell and `Get-Process | Select Name, PagedMemorySize, PrivateMemorySize` to get the memory size for each process and adding either column.

Should I be using a different column? or do I need to add something else besides the processes memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

This should match what you see in Task Manager

```
get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | Select @{L='commit';E={($_.totalvirtualmemorysize - $_.freevirtualmemory)*1KB/1GB}}
```

Comment: it does but I want to know what to add to get this number because processes (the way I tried) aren't adding up to the total

Comment: Good luck then.  You may want to read this answer to understand why what you’re after isn’t straight-forward.  https://superuser.com/a/974010

Comment: thanks, I read that and similar posts before posting my question but I don't see how it answers it or invalidates it. If the task manager or wmi can obtain the calculated committed size there should be a way to calculate it

Comment: Don't get me wrong.  I'm not making a judgement about whether your question is a valid or worthy one to ask, but I think that answer does a good job laying out that you have a challenge ahead if you want to find ALL the things that add up to total committed memory.  As it states, you can get close by digging into the "commit size" columns, but there are several other things that contribute to total commit charge.   It doesn't answer your question, but gives some perspective on why your question probably isn't going to be simple to find, with nice WMI or CIM classes you can just add up.