# Getting "out of memory" errors when around 65% used in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory

Since upgrading to Windows 10, I've noticed I get out-of-memory warnings (leading to out-of-memory app crashes if I don't address it) when my actual memory usage is only around 60% according to Task Manager. It wasn't an issue at first, but after the major update they did about a month ago, it seems to be happening more frequently.

I did occasionally run out of memory on Windows 7, but only when I was actually hitting 95+ percent usage, which was quite rare.

[image]
[I've attached a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sapv6.png) of task manager immediately before a crash, and it's typical of what I normally see - around 60-65% usage being flagged as "out of memory" territory. Where's my other one-third gone?

Current setup is Windows 10, with 4x4GB sticks of Corsair memory for 16GB total. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: "out of memory" errors are almost always an error indicating you are out of virtual memory.  Task Manager reports the usage of your physical system memory.

Answer (score 4):

You likely have pagefile disabled or severely limited. You need to go to the `Performance` tab and look at the `Commited` value. The "max" value listed there is your RAM + your enabled pagefile. If you disabled/limited page file it is likely what you are running out of.

[image]

For more detailed information about what is going wrong see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available/943185#943185) from a similar question.

Comment: I was hitting 18.1/20.8 GB committed according to that window, but I went and expanded my page file size and that at least let me launch the game without crashing. I'm thinking maybe there's an issue writing to the page file on one of the drives (I have them setup on two drives), or Windows isn't expanding one of them properly? Either way, since expanding the page file worked, I'm satisfied the problem lies there and so I'll mark this as a duplicate of the page file issue. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Being within 10% of max committed sounds about the right time for that error to be raised.