# Out Of Memory when plenty available

Tags: windows-10, memory

My computer often runs out of memory, even when there is a lot of memory free as shown by the Task Manager:

[image: Out of memory screenshot]

(Purely for reference, the labels in English:

[image])

I have no clue how to find out what is the problem.

**Additional informationThe virtual memory setting**

[image]

Comment: Well, it’s obviously not running out of virtual memory, that’s for sure. However, there are other limited resources (like GDI Handles and whatnot) that may be running out. Unfortunately, I don’t know how to detect that.

Comment: For the virtual memory part you may try to add/adjust the virtual RAM settings. A guide here http://ccm.net/faq/43000-adjust-default-virtual-memory-size-on-windows-10

Comment: It is running out of virtual memory. He has plenty of free physical memory but not enough backed virtual memory. He needs a bigger paging file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "out of memory" errors when around 65% used in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1024966/getting-out-of-memory-errors-when-around-65-used-in-windows-10)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That’s not correct. At “Committed” we can see there’s plenty of virtual memory available.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately, that number is not particularly useful. It excludes, for example, dirty memory-mapped pages that cannot be written back because the mapping is private. We know he's low on virtual memory because Windows produces that particular message when it cannot reserve more backing store. (But we also know what to investigate -- what is using so much backing store in an unusual way? And why is his pagefile so small?)

Comment: I do not change any page file or virtual memory setting. All is default of win10 Installation.

Comment: You still may try to change it now, if for some reason the initial setup did not do this the right way. See the link in my previous comment for how to do it.

Comment: I will change the virtual memory and see whether the problem still exist.

Comment: As others have pointed out that error message indicates you are running out of virtual memory not physical memory.  There is an easier solution to submitting screenshots that are translated, switch the language pack, makes it easier when we tell you to click stuff in order to fix your problem :-)

Comment: @Ramhound I will switch the language pack next time. sorry for that.

Comment: Well, to get detailed readings and satisfy everyone, you could use [RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/rammap.aspx) and provide a screenshot when the error appears again.

Comment: @DanielB _"At “Committed” we can see there’s plenty of virtual memory available."_ Yes, but that's after an allocation attempt failed and presumably the process that made the attempt is gone - along with all the commit it had allocated already. One needs to look at the current commit charge just before the failure. But given that the pagefile size has been expanded to almost the maximum it is clear that something recently needed a lot of commit. The right thing to try is to increase the initial and max pagefile, say to 16 and 32 GB. (Go on, just try it already!)

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I do as you say " increase the initial and max pagefile", The problem happened less. I recently remove a background clipboard application named "CLCL", The problem has gone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the initial and max pagefile make the problem happen less.
I recently removed a background clipboard application named "CLCL", The problem has gone. Thank you.