# No Graph Called ResidentSet

Tags: windows-10, performance, memory-leaks

Following the steps in the answer from here: [Windows 10 Memory Leak](https://superuser.com/questions/1160406/windows-10-memory-leak/1160640#1160640)

When it says "Open the MemUsage.etl with Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA.exe), drag and drop the graph ResidentSet from the left graph list to the analysis pane", there is such graph called ResidentSet.

Any idea why?

Comment: do you find the graph now? do you need more help? is the issue not fixed or not?

Answer (score 0):

it is there, expand the "Overview" called `Memory` first

[image]

Now you see it:

[image]

Also it looks like you use an old Windows Performance Toolkit version, because Windows 10 supports ReferenceSet, there is no need to modify my answers.