# Windows 10 possible memory leak

Tags: windows-10, memory-leaks

I updated Windows three weeks ago and since then I began having a high RAM % usage, even when there was no program on.
Today I realised that this might be a memory leak.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/b0L29mJ]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/b0L29mJ]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/b0L29mJ]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Updated what 3 times?

Comment: page and non-paged pool memory look a bit high in that screenshot.  How long had the computer been up when that was taken?  If you restart the computer and check those values what are they? Then after 5 mins and again after 1 hr for example.  It might be that poolmon is your best to identify a tag or tags of a particular driver that could be leaking memory.

Comment: I see your Page Table is huge. if you emptying all in RamMap (not sure if it would cause system instability) does it reduce the usage? I think the leak would come back later. it's really hard to know what caused the problem.

Comment: page table and (non)paged pools are too high, follow [this answer to debug both](https://superuser.com/a/1160640/174557)

Answer (score 1):

Run Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor. Make sure the memory line is open (expanded).

Let this run for 15 to 20 minutes. What Process comes to the top for memory consumption?

[image]

Also use MSCONFIG (Microsoft - Start Run MSCONFIG.EXE) to do a selective startup. Add processes until you see what process is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't think this helps. I have the same problem and neither task manager and resource monitor shows everything but RamMap does tell you what leaks. In my case, mapped page, pools and metafile caused leaks. Emptying all using RamMap (not sure if it would cause system instability) clears out the leaks temporary but it will come back later again. I'm still not sure what caused the leak yet

Comment: "mapped page, pools and metafile caused leaks. "  <-- That is not telling you what process. Use MSCONFIG (Microsoft) to do a selective startup. Add processes until you see what process is causing the issue.

Comment: That's not about process, see this article https://medium.com/@allenkuo/out-of-memory-find-leaked-ram-9200a1b8164. If it was caused by the process, you would see the issue on task manager or other easly. My mapped page, metafile and paged pool are bigger than usual so the issues are related to them!

Comment: That may be so, but processes and apps use memory so that is why I suggest a selective startup to see what.