# Windows 10 complaining about low memory, but there's plenty free?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I haven't messed with page file settings or anything like that, it's still set to be system managed.

[image]

Comment: This message refers to virtual memory exhaustion. Check the “Committed” figures. Please provide a screenshot of Sysinternals RAMMap.

Comment: What programs are you running and what are you doing when you receive these errors? Is it always a particular program or is it every program?

Answer (score -4):

Windows large memory management has been a problem since always. The amount of virtual memory available is the sum of physical memory and the pagefile size. Windows 10 does not handle memory allocation too logically from a user's perspective. Note that Committed memory does not necessarily use RAM and is not limited by the amount of available RAM.

Given your numbers and that you set the pagefile to 'system managed', you may have a memory leak.

Check the processes tab to see what's eating it up. If you don't notice anything relevant there, try process explorer and that will show you in detail what's consuming so much.

If the process you use is valid and you need it to actually be that large, you need should disable and re-enable the pagefile and probably add more memory.

-Edit-
Be also aware that not running some programs in administrator mode may cause them to load the paged memory. This can happen with some XP-times programs.

You could also use PrefMon as a helpful tool to count for Hard Faults (page reads/sec is a direct indication of that).

Comment: “Windows 10 does not handle memory allocation too logically from a user's perspective.” – You think? In fact, every modern OS does the same. It’s not Windows’ fault if an application reserves more memory than it actually uses.

Comment: It's not the applications that fail, it's the OS management. That's why the servers with TB-class sized memory (like SAP HANA) do not use Windows. In plain English, it's the OS has that 'promises' that the RAM or pagefile space will be available when it's needed and fails to keep that promise.

Comment: Why does it fail to keep that promise? This error message indicates it *would* fail to keep that promise very soon. If Windows runs out of virtual memory, you simply cannot reserve any more. You can only reserve memory you could actually use.

Comment: Because it should not reserve more while most of the actual RAM is practically available.

Comment: ? I don’t get what you’re referring to. This is all about commit. It’s not about physical memory. It’s not Windows that reserves the memory, it’s programs. If Windows didn’t use the pagefile to back those commitments, it might as well not exist at all.

Comment: It's not about using them, but about correctly using them. This explains the process in detail: https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available/943185#943185

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54928/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-overmind).