# Commit charge memory not reaching its full potential

Tags: windows, memory, iis, pagefile, web-application

I have several virtual IIS servers (2016) with multiple applications.
26 GB RAM
8 vCPU
Im getting lots of Event ID: 2004 in event viewer on several servers:

> Log Name:      System
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Resource-Exhaustion-Detector
> Event ID:      2004
> Task Category: Resource Exhaustion Diagnosis Events
> Level:         Warning
> Keywords:      Events related to exhaustion of system commit limit (virtual memory).
> User:          SYSTEM
> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: w3wp.exe (47500) consumed 1342939136 bytes, w3wp.exe (18704) consumed 1042980864 bytes, and w3wp.exe (10612) consumed 1007996928 bytes.

I moved the paging file to a separate 75GB size partition

however I still see the commit limit is ~35GB
[as mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/482678/commit-charge-is-100-full-but-physical-memory-is-just-60-when-using-no-page-fi), commit limit = current pagefile size + RAM size

1. why is the commit limit not growing to its full potential(26GBRAM+75GB PF)?
2. why does the w3wp.exe applications not consuming more memory if they need it ?

Comment: Are the w3wp executables 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: You say you moved the pagefile to a separate partition, but did you also set its size to ~75 GB? Did you check your workload for memory leaks? 300% pagefile size should not be necessary. // Also, what Mokubai said: The IIS workers are only using ~1 GB each. How many of them are there?

Comment: pagefiles are system managed.
id you check your workload for memory leaks? - no. any recommended method for that?
there are 15 different applications on each server

Comment: w3wp executables on 64 BIT (enable 32-bit application: false)